# Refactor an XPath expression: specify common subexpressions only once

Tags: xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

I would like to summarize sub-expressions of the XPath expression specified as the `test` attribute of an `<xsl:if>` instruction, which could appear multiple times (and as part of different Xpath expressions) in my xslt stylesheet. For example:

```
<xsl:if test="
  preceding-sibling::node()[
  (self::a and @attr1='a1') or
  (self::b and @attr2='b1')
  ] or
  following-sibling::node()[
  (self::a and @attr1='a1') or
  (self::b and @attr2='b1')
  ]
">
...
</xsl:if>
```

As you can see the sub-expression (`self::a and` ...) is repeated but the nodes upon which the predicate is applied may be different.

Comment: Your use of `local-name()` suggests that you have not declared namespaces properly. That's the first thing you should fix in your XSLT.

Comment: Ok, its just an example. I can use self::a or self::b instead. I edited the previous post.

Answer (score 0):

So, knowing nothing else about your remaining XSLT and the task you are solving, your current expression could be compressed into

```
<xsl:if test="
  preceding-sibling::a/@attr1='a1' or
  preceding-sibling::b/@attr2='b1' or
  following-sibling::a/@attr1='a1' or
  following-sibling::b/@attr2='b1'
">
...
</xsl:if>
```

Notes

- `(a or b) or (c or d)` is equivalent to `a or b or c or d`.
- `preceding-sibling::node()` also select text nodes, comments and so on. If you mean to select *elements*, using `node()` would be incorrect.
- `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` refers to *all* such siblings. `following-sibling::a/@attr1='a1'` tests whether any following sibling named `a` has an `attr1="a1"`.
  If you only mean the immediately following sibling, use `following-sibling::a[1]`.

Comment: Perhaps it could be shortened even further by using `../a`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, if the OP really means *all* `preceding-sibling`/`following-sibling` nodes. I am actually assuming he refers to the immediately neighboring elements only, see 3rd bullet point.

Comment: Could it be shorter? :)  Congrats on passing 200k

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it could be shorter. As indicated by Michael, `../a/@attr1='a1' or ../b/@attr2='b1'` would be an equivalent variant.

Comment: `../a/@attr1='a1' or ../b/@attr2='b1'` is not equivalent because this may select the context node, too

Answer (score 0):

If your processor supports functions e.g. exsl:functions then you could use

```
<fx:function name="my:testcondition">
    <xsl:param name="testnode"/>
    <fx:result select="$testnode/a/@attr1 = 'a1' or $testnode/b/@attr2 = 'b1'"/>
</fx:function>
```

You might have to use `exsl:node-set()` around the `$testnode`s as well and some namespace prefixed `my` for the function.

Then you could write

```
<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::node()[my:testcondition(.)] or following-sibling::node()[my:testcondition(.)]">
```

Now I see you xslt-2.0 tag, this is probably possible but myself can't give you details for that... :-(

Answer (score 0):

**XPath 2.0:**

```
  ../(* except .)
        [(self::a and @attr1='a1') 
        or
         (self::b and @attr2='b1')
         ]
```

---

**XSLT 2.0 using** `<xsl:function>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:function name="my:myFilter" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="pContext" as="node()"/>
      <xsl:sequence select=
       "$pContext/../(* except $pContext)
        [(self::a and @attr1='a1') 
        or
         (self::b and @attr2='b1')
         ]"/>
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**With the above function defined, one will call it as part of an XPath expression like this**:

```
my:myFilter(.)
```

---

**XSLT 1.0 / XPath 1.0**:

```
  ../*[count(.|current()) = 2]
        [(self::a and @attr1='a1') 
        or
         (self::b and @attr2='b1')
         ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Dimitre. This solution sounds good, but what if i want to use this expression on another part of my source code? Is it possible to save this part `self::a and @attr1='a1'` of my condition as a variable or something else?

Comment: @KaiFngmr, Not until XPath 3.0 where the function type (and inline functions) was introduced. In XSLT 2.0 one can have functions defined in XSLT, using the `<xsl:function>` declaration. Do you want me to add an `<xsl:function>` solution?

Comment: @KaiFngmr, I updated the answer with defining and using the expression as an `<xsl:function>`